# Chef recipe error: Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List

Tags: ruby, git, chef-infra, riak, knife

I have installed the following cookbooks via `knife`:

```
for cb in apt build-essential erlang java sysctl git ulimit yum yum-epel packagecloud riak curl ; do knife cookbook site install $cb; done;
```

And now when I run `sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[riak]'` I get an error complaining about the git dependency. However, the riak cookbook contains `"git": "~> 3.0",`.

The `git` cookbook that's installed is this version:

```
$ cat /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/git/metadata.rb | grep version
version           '4.0.2'
```

Here is the actual error for the command:

```
$ sudo chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[riak]'
Starting Chef Client, version 11.18.0.rc.1
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["riak"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
Could not satisfy version constraints for: git

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* riak


Running handlers:
[2014-11-15T01:48:55-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2014-11-15T01:48:55-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-11-15T01:48:55-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 3.588961624 seconds
[2014-11-15T01:48:55-05:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed "
[2014-11-15T01:48:55-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
root@test:~/chef/cookbooks/test#
```

Lastly here is the stacktrace if that's actually helpful to someone:

```
$ cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2014-11-15 01:48:55 -0500
Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed "
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:145:in `request'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/http.rb:126:in `post'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:168:in `sync_cookbooks'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:66:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:265:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:429:in `do_run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:33:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:33:in `<main>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint `"git": "~> 3.0"` means that it wants a version >= 3.0 and less than 4.0.

That is not satisfied by "4.0.2".

Reference:

- http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_versions.html

Comment: So what I ended up doing was: `berks install` and then move those to directories without version numbers in the `cookbook_path`. Is there a more intuitive way that I'm missing for this? I'm not using chef-solo, just the chef-client in local mode for now.

Comment: Rather than manually moving stuff, use the `berks vendor` command to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

`knife cookbook site install` doesn't actually grok versions of dependencies. It is an older tool that predates much of how modern cookbooks do dependencies. I recommend you use Berkshelf to manage your dependencies instead, it handles this kind of thing correctly.

To explain the issue in more detail, the `~> 3.0` constraint means anything from 3.0 up to but not including 4.0. `knife cookbook site install` just grabbed the latest version of the git cookbook which is 4.0.2, and thus outside the allowable range.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a cookbook it creates a folder named `nodes`. In this folder there is a json file with the names of the cookbook. Delete this folder and try again. It worked for me.